# How to solve "code couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.example.hello'."?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am using Xcode 8.3.3, and when I build my `HelloWorld` project, I get this error:

[image: cordova build ios]

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Check the signing section under general

Comment: @TahaAmini I ad my signing section into my question, can you help me check this?

Comment: The fact that you are even looking at the build settings for signing is a very Bad Smell. You should be doing all your management through the Project editor.

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: In Xcode editor first disable automatically managing signing. Try to set you signing manually. 
[image: In below image showing automatic code signing. Disable that one you will get manual code signing tabs]

Step 2: In signing set your provisional profile manually. There if you have any provisional profiles in your system it will appear if not found.

Step 3: Login developer account and go to your provisional certificates section.

Step 4: Check your project provisional created or not.

Step 5: If created check certificate is valid/invalid.

Step 6: If valid download your project certificate to your device. Else edit and download certificate and attach into keychain.

Step 7: Now your will find your provisional profiles in Xcode signing settings.

I hope it helps for you.

Comment: I could not find the checkbox to disable the automatically managing signing. And what do you mean by "set your provisional profile manually"? Sorry, I am quite new to this, do you mind to use pictures to elaborate?

Comment: Bravo! This worked for me, when all other solutions mentioned in SO failed.